# Why do I get hg: unknown command 'convert' althought running hg 1.7.3?

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial

I'm trying to convert an svn repo to mercurial but I fail.

```
$ hg convert http://memorizeasy.googlecode.com/svn hg-client
hg: unknown command 'convert'
Mercurial Distributed SCM


$ hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.7.3)
(see http://mercurial.selenic.com for more information)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The convert command works as an extension, i.e. it needs to be enabled explicitly in your `.hgrc` or `Mercurial.ini` file:

```
[extensions]
convert =
```

To check which extension commands currently are available, run `hg help extensions`. It lists enabled as well as disabled extensions.